# How to customize the Partner object in Account

Tags: lightning, account, person-accounts

I'm creating a relationship between "person account" and "person account" using the Partner object in the related list, and I don't know how I can add a new role for partner. In this case, I'm doing a project for a hospital, which has to include the following roles: doctor, nurse, patient, and relative. Please help me.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add roles for Partner using Classic (at least as of V57 - Spring 23)

[image]